# I'd have a symbol

Tags: knowledge, outer-space, symbols

A mutual friend of mine has gone crazy! They sent to my friend questions that don't make sense:

> Why is the letter V curvy????
>
> Why is letter O carrying plates on their head?
>
> What?? Why is the number 2 bumpy???
>
> Oh MY GOD! Why is that funny number pointing right?????
>
> Why does the letter N have a earring???
>
> M, why did you do fishing??

Another mutual friend has done that too but with a different approach:

> I am gonna circle the multiplication sign.
>
> Why is the female sign a demon???
>
> Oh ok, its back.
>
> As I said, I am gonna also circle the addition sign.
>
> Oh god, I erased the line from Males.
>
> I can't solve this math problem, 21? or 24?

**What are they talking about?**

Here's a bonus:

> Continue the two things that they sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first friend

> appears to be describing the zodiac symbols: ♈, ♉, ♊, ♋, ♌, ♍. (The "plates" are the horns of ♉, the "funny number" is 69, and the "fish" is the right side of the symbol.)

Similarly, the second friend

> is describing the planetary symbols (starting with the sun): ☉, ☿, ♀, ⊕, ♂, ♃. ("It's back" is referring to the normal 'female' sign, which also represents Venus. The "math problem" is a symbol that looks vaguely like a ligature of either 21 or 24.)